# str.suffix in z3 API is unknown

Tags: z3, suffix

I'm trying to use suffix API function in Z3 in the following script,
but Z3 complains it does not know str.suffix. Since I see it in the API
[here](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/src/api/z3_api.h#L3328) I guess it exists but only called different (?)
Thanks!

```
(declare-const s   String)
(declare-const s00 String)
(declare-const s1  String)
(declare-const s2  String)
(declare-const i      Int)

(assert (= s "X2a2@@aDD\x00444ppa800"))

(assert (= s00 (str.substr s 0 (str.indexof s "\x00" 0))))

(assert (str.suffixof s1 s00))
(assert (str.suffixof s2  s1))

(assert (= (str.len s1) (+ (str.len s2) 1)))

(assert (or (and (str.contains s00 "a")
                 (str.contains s1  "a"))
            (not (str.contains s00 "a"))))

(assert (not (str.contains s2 "a")))

(assert (= i (ite (not (str.contains s00 "a")) -1
(- (str.len s00) (str.len s1)))))

(check-sat)
(get-value (s s00 s1 s2 i))
```

EDIT:

The script was fixed according to the answer. Here is the output from z3:

```
sat
((s "X2a2@@aDD\x00444ppa800")
 (s00 "X2a2@@aDD")
 (s1 "aDD")
 (s2 "DD")
 (i 6))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct call is: `str.suffixof`

(PS. Your file still doesn't load even with that fix since it has other issues; but that's besides the point of this question.)

Comment: Thanks! I've fixed the script and now it's working fine